# What are our options for avoiding the J1 2 Year Home Residency Requirement?

Tags: usa, j-visa

My wife is from Tunisia, and came to the US in 2021 on a J1 visa that was sponsored by the Dep of State through a Thomas Jefferson Scholarship. This exchange scholarship allowed her to be in the US for only 3 months in 2021 due to Covid, not the usual year that others who received this scholarship got. This visa came with the 2-Year Home Residency requirement, meaning she will have to spend 2 cumulative years back in Tunisia before being able to adjust her status in the US to get either a work visa or a green card, even in cases of marriage to a US citizen. She could however get an F1 visa, which is what she did to get her Master's degree. She started that in September of 2022 and is finishing this semester in May 2024.

So now we are here. Regarding waivers and getting rid of the requirement for us to leave the country to go to Tunis, lawyers have told us that we do not qualify for Persecution, Hardship or No Objection. So, we have just been trying to find an Interested Federal Government Agency to hire her, as that's the only real option we can see for a shot at a waiver.

The USCIS told us that she is not under the J1 requirement anymore because she is an F1 holder now, but we know that to be wrong.

We are essentially only considering stopping our life in the US and going back, or dumping $$ into lawyers to HOPE to get this requirement waived.

Comment: You could always spend 2 years in Tunisia together? It's super annoying and the policy is downright moronic but it is what it is...

Comment: Your wife presumably signed up for her US visas knowing the rules. Save yourself the lawyer fees and stress, go home for the required period.

Comment: Have you actually examined the No Objection certificate route? See https://www.tunisianembassy.org/j1-212e-waiver I have no idea what that “commitment” entails though.

Comment: Note however that [Recommendation applications are denied when the reasons given for requesting the waiver do not outweigh the program and foreign policy considerations of the exchange visitor program. For this reason, waiver recommendation applications from exchange visitors who received U.S. government funding are generally denied.](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/study/exchange/waiver-of-the-exchange-visitor/exchange-waiver-faqs.html)